# Second-countable topological space, limit point implies limit of sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

IF $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is second-countable and $S \subset X$, does it follow that every limit point of $S$ is a limit of a sequence in $S$?

Comment: Yes, you only need first-countable for this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be second-countable, and $S \subset X$. Suppose $x$ is a limit point of $S$, i.e. $x \in \overline{S}$. Let $\{U_i\}$ be the set of open sets from the countable basis that contain $x$; as the space is second-countable, we know that $\{U_i\}$ is countable, and we can enumerate the sets as $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_n, \dots$.

Let $V_j = \bigcap_{i=1}^j U_i$. Each $V_j$ is a finite intersection of open sets, so is open. Since $x$ is a limit point of $S$, for each $j$, there exists an $x_j \in V_j \cap S$. We claim that $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $S$ that converges to $x$. By construction, $\{x_j\}$ is a sequence of points in $S$.

Now, if $U$ is any open set that contains $x$, there exists an open set $U_N$ in the countable basis such that $x \in U_N \subset U$. For any $n \ge N$, we have that $x_n \in V_n$. Moreover, $U_N$ is one of the sets in the intersection that defines $V_n$, so that $V_n \subset U_N$. This implies that $x_n \in U_N$ for all $n \ge N$, so $x_n \to x$, as desired.